# Omisión en WHERE SQL Server

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Necesito una sentencia para quitar todo lo que provenga de un dominio de correo especifico  de mi columna `[From]`. Ejemplo: `@dominio_especifico.com`

Y se me complica la forma de quitarlo porque debo dejarlo si proviene de las direcciones que contienen `feedback+###`. Ejemplo: `feedback001@dominio_especifico.com`
Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```sql
WHERE [From] NOT LIKE '%@dominio_especifico%' OR 
[From] LIKE '%feedback%@dominio_especifico%'
```

Y solo es para una sentencia porque tengo mas variantes de correos y dominios, pero esas entran por defaul en lo que debo dejar en vista.
Necesito de un empujón con esto.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución pude hallarla al combinar 2 consultas `SELECT` con la utilización del operador `UNION`.

EL SQL que utilicé fué el siguiente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sql_test_a a
WHERE a.FIRST_NAME  NOT LIKE '%@dominio_especifico%' 
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM sql_test_a a
WHERE a.FIRST_NAME LIKE 'feedback%'
```

Aquí te paso los inserts y la tabla de prueba que utilicé:

```
CREATE TABLE sql_test_a 
( 
    ID         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
); 


INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('1', '@dominio_especifico.com'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('2', 'feedback001@dominio_especifico.com'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('3', 'feedback002@dominio_especifico.com'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('4', 'feedback001@inio_eifico.com'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('5', 'feedback001@ilkajd.com');
```

Y aquí los resultados arrojados:

```
ID  FIRST_NAME
2   feedback001@dominio_especifico.com
3   feedback002@dominio_especifico.com
4   feedback001@inio_eifico.com
5   feedback001@ilkajd.com
```

Claramente cumple los requisitos de evitar el dominio especifico excepto en los casos de que contenga el mensaje 'feedback'.

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: En efecto, la solución mas factible era `UNION` gracias bro. Saludos!

Comment: De nada hermano!